# Show a function is linear

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, multivariable-calculus

[image]

I'm asked to show that for $x \in \mathbb{R^2}$ that $h:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $h(t) = f(tx)$ is differentiable by first showing it is linear.

The solutions say to use $g(x) = -g(-x)$ but I can't understand why

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**. Showing that a function $h \colon \def\R{\mathbf R}\R \to \R$ is linear is equivalent to show that it fulfills 
$$ h(t) = t\cdot h(1), \qquad t \in \R $$
Consider three cases: $t > 0$, $t = 0$ and $t < 0$ (that's the part where $g(x) = -g(-x)$ comes in handy, as it reduces the last case to the first you've already done).